# Error loading a configuration file when starting a process from web page

Tags: c#, configuration

I have a web page which I am using to start a process.  The process is a .net 2.0 executable that has a config file. If I run the executable by itself, I have no errors.  The process is starting the executable (it's writing to a log file, and I can see that the output has been generated).

As soon as my executable tries to reference it's config file (but only when it has been launched from the web page) it throws an exception ("Configuration system failed to initialize
"), which contains this:

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: An error occurred
>   loading a configuration file: Access is denied.

I'm kind of stumped.  How can I get my executable to load the config file?

BTW, I did check that the current directory is still the directory of the executable.

EDIT here's my code:

```
        System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        string mappedFile = Server.MapPath(@".\my.exe");
        p.StartInfo.FileName = mappedFile;
        p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Server.MapPath(@".\");
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
        string eco = COAuditBox.Text;
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        string filename = eco + "_" + String.Format("{0:yyyyMMddHHmmss}", now) + ".txt";
        string redirectUrl = "reports/" + filename;
        string redirectFile = Server.MapPath(redirectUrl);
        //File.WriteAllText(redirectFile, "TEST\t\n");
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = eco + " \"" + redirectFile + "\"";
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: How does the Web page starts the process? Which browser are you using?

Comment: @Aerik : more or less the same issue here ... did you find a solution ?

Comment: @SébastienNussbaumer I did solve it, but the code is off running on some server somewhere that I don't even remember :-( I'll see if I can dig it up...

Answer (score 1):

Under which user is your web application running? This user probably doesn't have the correct permissions to access the .config file. Either give the user correct permissions, OR run the app under a different account.

UPDATE: to diagnose the problem, use [Process Monitor from Microsoft/sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645). It allows you to watch file access operations. You can filter by process name and/or file name. This should point you in the right direction.

Comment: The web app is impersonating a local user.  How would it be able to access the exe and not the confile file?

Comment: under what trust level does your asp.net app run (do you have a securityPolicy section in web.config)?

Comment: also, you may want to use process monitor to help diagnosing the problem (see link in update)